# how to create shortcode in wordpress for portfolio?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am in need to create wordpress shortcode of portfolio with multiple features for the customers to select and after that i am want to integrate with visual composer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though very basic, this is what I've done recently to add a element block to Visual Composer in the form of a shortcode:

```
<?php
// Shortcode function to insert a 'read more' button in VC
function insert_readmore($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'link' => '#',
        'text' => 'Read more',
        'align' => 'left'
    ), $atts));

    $readmore = "<p><a href=\"" . $link . "\" class=\"btn readmore " . $align . " \">" . $text . "</a></p>";
    return $readmore;
}

function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode('btnreadmore', 'insert_readmore');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
?>
```

After this I mapped the shortcode

> [btnreadmore link=http://google.com align=right text=More]

in the Visual Composer settings. Once mapped, Visual Compser adds a new tab in the 'add element' screen that you can insert in a Visual Composer column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try this one. Actually i am looking to create shortcode for portfolio any tutorial or idea will be great.